# Avro Serialization from generics

Tags: scala, generics, avro

This is a very simple example based on the GitHub page of [Avro4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s), and it  **works fine**.

```
object Main extends App {

  case class Ingredient(name: String, sugar: Double, fat: Double)
  case class Pizza(name: String, ingredients: Seq[Ingredient], vegetarian: Boolean, vegan: Boolean, calories: Int)

  val pepperoni = Pizza("pepperoni", Seq(Ingredient("pepperoni", 12, 4.4), Ingredient("onions", 1, 0.4)), false, false, 98)
  val hawaiian = Pizza("hawaiian", Seq(Ingredient("ham", 1.5, 5.6), Ingredient("pineapple", 5.2, 0.2)), false, false, 91)

  val format = RecordFormat[Pizza]
  val recordInAvro = format.to(pepperoni)
  printf(s"Avro of Pepperoni: $recordInAvro\n")
}
```

But what I would like to do is something this:

```
object Main extends App {

  case class Ingredient(name: String, sugar: Double, fat: Double)
  case class Pizza(name: String, ingredients: Seq[Ingredient], vegetarian: Boolean, vegan: Boolean, calories: Int)

  val pepperoni = Pizza("pepperoni", Seq(Ingredient("pepperoni", 12, 4.4), Ingredient("onions", 1, 0.4)), false, false, 98)
  val hawaiian = Pizza("hawaiian", Seq(Ingredient("ham", 1.5, 5.6), Ingredient("pineapple", 5.2, 0.2)), false, false, 91)

  def toAvro[T](obj: T): GenericRecord = RecordFormat[T].to(obj)

  val recordInAvro = toAvro[Pizza](pepperoni)
  printf(s"Avro of Pepperoni: $recordInAvro\n")
}
```

However, even though this last piece of code seems fine, I get the following error during compilation time:

```
Error:(14, 54) could not find implicit value for parameter toRecord: com.sksamuel.avro4s.ToRecord[T]
  def toAvro[T](obj: T): GenericRecord = RecordFormat[T].to(obj)
Error:(14, 54) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit toRecord: com.sksamuel.avro4s.ToRecord[T], implicit fromRecord: com.sksamuel.avro4s.FromRecord[T])com.sksamuel.avro4s.RecordFormat[T] in object RecordFormat.
Unspecified value parameters toRecord, fromRecord.
  def toAvro[T](obj: T): GenericRecord = RecordFormat[T].to(obj)
```

Any tips on how to make the Avro serialisation work with generics? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your definition to

```
def toAvro[T: ToRecord: FromRecord](obj: T): GenericRecord = RecordFormat[T].to(obj)
```

More info [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html) and [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html)

In a nutshell: when you are using concrete type compiler could automatically find required `ToRecord` implicit value. But in a parameterized code you should promise compiler you will supply this implicit value to it somehow.

Comment: The links you sent me were quite useful. Turns out that the definition you wrote is almost there. The correct answer is `def toAvro[T](obj: T)(implicit toR: ToRecord[T], fromR: FromRecord[T]): GenericRecord = RecordFormat[T].to(obj)`. Thank you :)

Comment: @Rick Added second implicit to the answer